# Alternative to WHERE NOT EXISTS or the LEFT OUTER JOIN method

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two big tables (tabla A and table B). I want to synchronize table B with table A (adding missing records). When I however use NOT EXIST or use the LEFT OUTER JOIN method for this, it gives a timeout. Any other solutions to perform this trick out there?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on joined columns?

Comment: There is `not in`, but that's usually slower.

Comment: @RomanPekar both tables have indexes. I don't have a concatenated cross table index though. Is that even possible?

Comment: Share the query and its execution plan with us

Comment: Well if you'll post your query and tables schema it will be easier to help you. You can also make example on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding foreign key constraint at table B

Comment: It's a good thing that your problem got solved but **adding a foreign key doesn't add missing records**.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers true, but after adding the foreign key constraint NOT EXIST or the LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't give a timeout anymore and therefore the question is answered. Now through NOT EXISTS or LEFT OUTER JOIN i can add the missing records.

Comment: Adding a FK can improve performance *(at least on SQL Server)* but not in the same order of magnitude as an index does *(and you already confirmed the indexes exist)*. I'm not questioning your statement but it doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I'm not sure about MS SQL but in mysql when you create a FK contraint a BTREE index is automatically generated. The local indexes were indeed already defined. I think it's better to stop talking here because otherwise other people will start complaining it's too chatty.